# How to get Md5 hash value in SQL Server CE 4.0

Tags: sql, hash, sql-server-ce, md5

How to get MD5 Hash value in SQL Server CE 4.0?

I tried following but I am getting unregognized function for `Hashbytes`, at SQL Server CE toolbox for Visual Studio

```
select CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'email@dot.com'), 2)
```

> The function is not recognized by SQL Server Compact. [ Name of function = HashBytes,Data type (if known) =  ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hashbytes function is not supported in SQL Server Compact, you can use the .NET ComputeHash function instead